# How to use JRebel existing licence

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jrebel

I am using JRebel free Social plan in my Eclipse Hellios. Now I am using Eclipse Juno.
I have installed JRebel plugin in it and now I want to use that social plan for JRebel which I have activate it with my previous eclipse. So my question is how do I use JRebel with my new eclipse which I have previously activated. Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: should just work.. Check from JRebel Config Center, the licensing tab, what information does it print?

Comment: @Anton Arhipov  thanks for rply I found what I need ...(: